# Food Delivery app using foreground location to store in firebase

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation

I am building a food delivery app using firebase. in my driver side I want to get the location while my location can have only foreground permission. But when the source and destination link appears I am navigating to google maps app for the navigation at that time my app is stop sending location updates to the firestore. I understand that the app is in background mode but in case of zomato and swiggy they also requires foreground location permission only. I just want to know what I am missing that it cannot update the location while in paused state. Give the solution for flutter and if that is elaborative is better, as I dont have much experience in location service.

At first I have tried using background location package that is available in pub.dev.
I have checked that when the app state changes to paused state it is not sending the location update.
I am using geolocator package which does not work with background state of the app .
in the initState of that screen I am using a Stream to send the location update.

I am expecting the app to perform the navigation for the origin and destination link to google maps and when the app is in background state(paused state) then also it should update the location to firebase.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.